# Which ports uses unity when it runs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coap

I made a car movement simulation with Unity, now I need to implement CoAP protocol, in an example made in C# I see that they use this 
            `string urlToCall = "coap://localhost:5683/sensors/temp";`

So I guess I need to know the URL of Unity, but I don't know where Unity runs by default

Could you help me? please

Comment: By Unity, what **exactly** do you mean? I'm pretty sure Unity doesn't spin up a coap server by default. You will need to add a CoAP server implementation to your software.

Comment: I'm using Unity 3D, I created a car movement simulation in a city. Yes, Unity by default doesn't spin up a CoAP server. That's why I'm trying to use a C# implement ation for it. In the CoAP official web page there are examples, in all I see they use that variable "urlToCall". I guess I need to put there the Unity server URL.

Comment: If the "unity server", which I have no idea what you mean by, doesn't implement CoAP, you cannot simply point a CoAP client to it. The CoAP protocol is a protocol for a client and a server to talk together, you need both. Unity doesn't spin up or implement neither.

Comment: Yes, I know Unity doesn't implement CoAP. How can I get the events that Unity is receiving from the keyboard? Because I need to implement CoAP protocol with Unity.

Comment: Unity is not by default a server  of anything.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, maybe you are looking for this :

```
import psutil

procs = list(psutil.process_iter())


for x in procs:
    if x.name()=="UnityPackageManager.exe":
         print(x,"\n------------\n")
         print(x.connections())
    '''
    else :
         print(x)
    '''
```

You can tweak the process name if you want it for something else.

[Github](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/Process-Tapping/blob/master/port_from_process.py)